# SimpleXMLElement access Array

Tags: php

Simple question but it's really causing me problems!

I have a var dump as follows; how do I access the array `["slot_id"]` and get it as an actual array? I've tried `$object->slot_id`, `$object['slot_id']` and `$object[0]` with no success. I think I'm just missing something ^_^

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#17 (1) {
  ["slot_id"]=>
  array(143) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "41"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "42"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "43"
    ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleXML does not implement the ArrayAccess iterator, unfortunately.  There are several code samples in the comments of the [php.net](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php#105697) documentation page for how to get a SimpleXML object as an array, but I've found it frustrating enough to avoid using it when possible.  I have not tried any of these myself, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: This is a simpleXMlElement with an array in it, surely there has to be a way to get to it?

Comment: You can traverse (since SimpleXML does implement [Traversable](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php)) slot_id as if it were an array, but if you want to extract it as an array, I think you have to loop through the whole thing.  Not ideal, I know.  `foreach ($xml->slot_id as $slot) echo "\n".$slot;`.  You can also point to an index like `$xml->slot_id[2]` (giving you 43), but you can't use it in a method that expects an array, such as `implode()`.  Hope this helps.